# What does "first cut" mean?

Tags: meaning

In software engineering, I sometimes see "first cut" in a context where it could mean "first version".

Is it some idiom? Where does it come from? Does it mean literally "first version", or is there any emotional subtext, or did I misunderstand its meaning completely?

Comment: @NigelJ but the pre-industrial examples in that search have nothing to do with grass, and most have nothing to do with any form of agriculture.

Comment: @NigelJ below the ngram there are some buttons with ranges of years for this purpose.

Comment: @phoog Yes, indeed. They seem to be cutting everything around them - except crops.

Comment: Purely FTR, I have never, ever, ever heard that used with software. I think you're simply wrong, or misheard it.  (As it happens, I work in both film/tv, and, software.)

Comment: Is there a chance you work for a company that makes TV shows, as well as software?

Comment: @Fattie No. But maybe that particular person has that background — I cannot know.

Comment: @anatolyg , please note that it is absolutely ubiquitous in English to re-use phrases extremely flexibly in totally disparate situations.  Please note that I have **edited** your question based on the new information you have given.  your question really gave the wrong sense of the situation.  Pls note that you can and should instantly re-edit your question, if you're not happy with a helpful edit someone has made.  Cheers!

Comment: Heard it from at least 2 different people (maybe more), so can't say "once".

Comment: Great!  Just understand that it is **a term from film and TV production**. It's totally commonplace in English to use a phrase evocatively in different fields or ways.  Cheers!

Comment: FWIW, @Fattie, I am pretty familiar with the term "first cut" as an initial version of pretty much *anything* that is expected to be subject to further refinement.  Definitely including software, in which context I sometimes use the term myself.  Its origins are undoubtedly in the film industry, but neither I nor anyone in my immediate circle has any affiliation with TV or film production.

Comment: John - very interesting.  It could be one of those common things on this site where you're just much younger than me, and, more connected to certain linguistic circles.

Comment: I haven't seen any of the answers mention that, but "first cut" reminds of the "lion's share". When dividing something among several people, the person who gets the "first cut" is going to get a more favourable share.

Comment: The correct answer may depend on more context than given in the question. What is contained inside 1st "cut" and subsequent "cuts"? Many years ago, delivering SW for a French client, a new project's functionality was divided into (what project management termed) "tranches"(=slices/cuts of e.g. bread), which were delivered at certain deadlines. OTOH the movie editing metaphor may be quite appropriate in an Agile environment where subsequent iterations refine the project based on user feedback.

Comment: @Stef it's completely unrelated to the phrase "first cut" as in "first cut is the deepest".

Comment: By the way, I encounter the term more often in the sense of “the first stage of winnowing a long list of candidates”.  A *shortlist* consists of those candidates who were not cut out in the early round(s), and thus passed the first cut(s).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It simply means a first (presumably complete in some way, such as an alpha version or minimum viable product) version of the software or documentation which is expected to require further work before it is finalized. The origin is in the [film industry](https://raindance.org/the-6-stages-of-editing-as-a-film-director/).

> 3. Rough Cut and Variations The rough cut can take up to three months to complete. Each editor works differently. Sometimes the editor works
>    alone and shows the day or weeks work to the director and producer,
>    Sometimes the editor and director work together, discussing every
>    nuance.
>
> In the rough cut, the scenes are placed in order and checked for
> continuity. This all-important step in the editing process allows for
> revisions and new ideas to be tried and tested.
>
> Hint: Make the edit points between the scenes very obvious in order to
> emphasise the ‘roughness’. Failure to do so may result in the editor
> committing to an edit before it is ready.
>
> 4. First Cut The first cut is the rough cut that is accepted by the editor, the director and the producer. Selection and sequence are
>    basically fixed, although changes can still be made. The later film is
>    visible. Detailed fine cut starts out from its proportions,
>    structures, rhythms and emphasises them. Hint: Never be afraid to let
>    the first cut ‘rest’ for a few days so everyone involved can see it
>    with fresh eyes.

We can see a fairly early example (by software and Internet standards - February of 1971) in [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc97) document, which is not actually referring to software but to specifications for software:

```
A FIRST CUT AT A PROPOSED TELNET PROTOCOL

1    Introduction

       This paper describes a first cut at a proposed Telnet protocol.
   _Telnet_ is a process which runs at a _user's_ _site_ and allows him
   to utilize a typewriter-like terminal to gain interactive service
   from a remote _server_ _site over the ARPA Network.
```

I have also heard "rough cut" in this context but I don't think there is a strong distinction between the two terms in the context of software. They both refer to something that is clearly unfinished but adequate to be discussed, evaluated and improved upon (slightly different than the film industry definition).

Comment: "It simply means ..." no, it's a metaphor.  "The origin is ..." the actual literal meaning of a metaphor isn't an "origin", it's just the meaning.  (Note that in your example of an academic paper, where the academic paper is described as a first cut - they are using a metaphor.)

Comment: @Fattie I would hold that once the users are no longer conscious of the origins of the phrase, as they are using it, it becomes etymology and is no longer a metaphor. Is "book" a metaphor because it originated from the wood used to carve runes?

Comment: Spehro - you're 100% correct of course.  Metaphors can become "an 'actual' word".  Interestingly, "edit" is a very bad metaphor for film assembly. You can "edit" a still picture (imagine retouching), you can edit some text, but you can not edit film, you can only "assemble" it different ways (ie, by changing the order/selection of the frames used).  Hence "edit" was, or is, a metaphor (from writing) for film cutting, but, "edit" is now the word we use.  (Edit, in the film context, has a totally different meaning from edit, in the text context - but both meanings are now in the dictionary.) ...

Comment: In the specific example at hand, any functioning human alive today would know that "first cut" is a film industry term. (Just for example, you often see "Director's Cut" on, you know, Ridley Scott films and such!)  And they would thus realize, as they utter the words "first cut", they're making a kind of clever joke or reference. It's inconceivable (as we write, 2023) that there's anyone so non-functioning who doesn't realize it's a joke/reference.  (Exactly as when one of my colleagues refers to her oldest kid as a "first draft".) So, it's a joke/metaphor.

Comment: (Obviously, and of course, a non-English speaker may not have a clue what the utterance "first cut" means in any way - hence the question. The answer being "it's a TV industry term" and "it's being used as a metaphor".)  {Then, as perhaps yourself is pointing out, you assert "it's fairly commonly used as a metaphor" and indeed you further have pointed out "it could be a word in 20 years".}  [Exactly as for example, when people say "filmed in Hollywood" now (ie, on digital equipment) extremely few people realize "film" is doubly-removed from the original meaning.]

Answer (score 40):

> The first cut is the rough cut that is accepted by the editor, the director and the producer [of a film, usually without sound, music, or titles].  Selection and sequence are basically fixed, although changes can still be made. The later film is visible. Detailed fine cut starts out from its proportions, structures, rhythms and emphasises them.
> *From [The 6 stages of editing as a film director](https://raindance.org/the-6-stages-of-editing-as-a-film-director/)*
>
> In the earliest days of filmmaking, directors had to cut the film
> stock apart with scissors and then tape it back together to create new sequences.
> *From [Adobe](https://www.adobe.com/creativecloud/video/hub/ideas/what-is-a-rough-cut)*

In the context of software, I have never heard this term in my entire career in that domain. But, it is clear that the expression refers to an **alpha version** of the software (*possibly a pre-alpha version*, see [Software release cycle at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle)).

Comment: The expression may also be influenced by the usage of *cut* in baseball, where it means a swing of the bat. “Just as the batter took his cut, the pitch dropped six inches and snapped unobstructed into the catcher’s mitt.”

Comment: +1 to this. OP's colleague has used an incorrect metaphor to describe software. He clearly means 'first pass' or 'first iteration'

Comment: It wasn't just the earliest days: most movies were still filmed just 15 years ago, so that means cutting and pasting (though with better tools).

Comment: It never clicked until I read this what the origin of the expression was, but I have used it and heard it in many domains as a synonym for "first try" or "first version."

Comment: @Richard It's not an incorrect metaphor, it's quite common in a number of countries I've worked in

Comment: In film production, it has utterly, utterly, utterly, utterly nothing to do with baseball. Anyone can instantly google why "cut" means "edit" in film-making.

Comment: As graffito says, the expression is totally unused in app production.  You can an early version of an app an alpha, or other software terms.

Comment: @Richard 's comment just here is the **most astute**.  It was almost certainly a non-English speaker who meant "first pass" or "first iteration".

Comment: "Cut" is used today (usually in an "Edit" menu along with "copy" and "paste") in text editing as well, referencing a time when it was common for authors and editors to physically cut paragraphs of text out of a page to see if an article would read better in a different order.

Comment: @Richard It would be an incorrect literal statement. But since it's a metaphor, it's perfectly fine. "Can you come up with a query for the new report?" "It's not really my strong suite, but I'll take a swing at it." Some time later, "Here is a first cut of the query you wanted, can you take a look at it and tell me if it fills the bill?" This is fine, even if the report in question doesn't involve card games, baseball, film making, or theater.

Comment: @Fattie I have to assume you're in the US and that the term isn't common there, because it's a perfectly valid term in software development in Ireland, England and Australia. Just because you don't have personal experience of a phrase does not mean "it was almost certainly a non-English speaker"

Comment: hi @Mohirl  I'm from Scotland originally and spend much time in all these places. To cut to the chase.  **It's a metaphor.**  The question in the title "What does "first cut" mean?" can be answered in one and only one way.  When used with (say) software it's a metaphor.  "it's a perfectly valid term..." yes, it's a metaphor.  You may also hear people saying "first draft..." as a metaphor.  The other day I heard someone call an alpha a "foetus", another metaphor.  user3067860's comment flawlessly explains the situation.

Comment: @Fattie Yes, I'm aware it's a metaphor. Which is a perfectly valid use of the phrase. You're the one who claimed that doing so means the individual must be a non-English speaker who must have meant "first pass" (which seems far less common based on a 30-second google search).

Answer (score 13):

Adding to Graffito's answer, I've encountered the term many times in UK software development organisations. First cut software is certainly pre-alpha, and usually never seen outside the development team.

It usually means "The first version that works well enough to evaluate." When you're doing something that's new to you, you quite often want to see at an early stage if what you're doing actually makes sense. Does the UI provide the necessary controls? Does the algorithm run at a plausible speed? What is obviously missing? What is clearly unnecessary, when you try using it?

A first cut may be explicitly a prototype, intended to guide the design of a real implementation, or it may be intended to be developed into a real product. Irrespective of that, it's a test for the practicality of a concept, which lets you see if you're on a plausible path, or if you need to rethink your approach.

A first cut may be a formal part of a development process, or it may simply be the stage at which a developer first wants to show their work to a colleague or a supervisor, to get a second opinion.

Comment: As it happens I have never, ever, ever heard that used with software.  (As it happens, I work in both film/tv, and, software!)  I'm from the UK originally and work extensively in Europe, the US, Asia.  I don't dispute your report, but, the OP should be aware it is (possibly?) just wrong.

Comment: It's a bit hard to define what could be considered "wrong" when talking about language. For me, an independent report which mentions a figure of speech I heard is very valuable. If someone has never heard that particular expression, that's also a bit valuable, but much less.

Comment: The overwhelming facts are (1) it is an everyday, absolutely established term ***in film production***.  I believe OP is not aware of that.  (2) It is not commonly used in app/software production.  Really, that's that.

Comment: It is not *universally* used in software work, but do you have grounds for saying it is not common? The fields of software production where I've encountered it have very little to do with films or TV, making it plausible they'd use the term incorrectly.

Comment: Hi John, to repeat, i absolutely respect your report that you've heard it used.  Do note that, literally, every single question on here which is about "how are words used in speech" (say, 90% of the questions) can only be answered in one possible way .. "based on my experience".  by grounds for saying "it is not common" are 20 years of experience in every part of the software industry, all over the world.  The overwhelming fact is., it's utterly commonplace in English to re-use phrases extremely flexibly in totally disparate situations. i've heard someone refer to their first child as

Comment: "first cut!"  It would be nonsensical to then ask on here "is that a child raising term?" the other day someone said to me something like "well we're on the first hole" (as in a golf course) about some app.  It doesn't make it a "software term".  Moreover, the OP has now explained that **he heard one person using this**.  Really, it's wildly overthinking it other than to explain the meaning of the phrase (for anyone who, oddly, has not heard "cut" used to mean "edit") and note that, of coursae, it can be used figuratively in any field or conversation.

Comment: Let's say that ("unknown to me") "first cut" or perhaps "batter" or perhaps "rough mix" has become common fun slang among young programmers to mean an alpha.  The answer to the question (presumably by a non-English speaker) would be exactly as it is now.  You'd explain what "first cut" or "batter" or "rough mix" means in the fields of film / cooking / music.  And then you'd point out that (of course, obviously) it's ubiquitous in English to re-use phrases all over the place. That's really all there is to it!

Comment: @Fattie I doubt it's anything to do with young programmers, if anything I would guess it is older people who use more "literary" or "academic" phrasing. Here are a few examples from different contexts, you can see it has a long history of general usage: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-387-21623-2_2 https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Civil_Engineering/Fundamentals_of_Transportation/02%3A_Planning_Models/2.04%3A_Modes https://www.nytimes.com/2000/01/23/opinion/fighting-for-teacher-quality.html https://lawreview.uchicago.edu/print-archive/unbundling-criminal-trial-rights-0

Comment: @Fattie I wouldn't say it's a software term per se but rather a business term which has spread to common usage. You will find lots of use of the phrase "first cut" to refer to a draft version of a text document or even a rough expression of an idea. It appears in an O'Reilly book on data migration referring to "first cut of a migration plan" (book was published in 2012 so perhaps the author is young since I haven't bought a technical book published after 1998). I think it's hard to argue that software isn't essentially text documents or software development isn't a business activity.

Comment: @Fattie It's possible that the opposite is true. You haven't heard the term used in your industry because you're too young? Spehro Pefhany found an excellent usage of the phrase from an RFC from 1971

Comment: Yes, and: I've heard "first cut" applied to sub-products where "alpha" might not make sense. "I've done a first cut at the data model" or "We've got a first cut of the landing page." -- You wouldn't call the processing section in alpha if you weren't doing any processing yet, and you wouldn't call the UI in alpha if all you have is a landing page.

Answer (score 3):

"First cut" is a term used in film and TV production.

Headline question:

> What does "first cut" mean?

**It means editing a film. (The word "cut" is used because with old-style plastic film, you literally cut it with a pair of scissors to edit the film.)**

The answer and the only answer to the question "What does "first cut" mean?" is "editing film or TV shows".

The fact that the OP overhead it used in an engineering or software field - is irrelevant. It's utterly commonplace in English to re-use phrases extremely flexibly in totally disparate situations.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it a lot with documents (memos, policies, essays, even PowerPoints or engineering drawing pages) in the US military and consulting firms (which can be a little slang-y).

It just means first version, without much negative or positive feeling.  Maybe a slight connotation of just taking a hack at something (cut is a little colloquial). It would not seem strange to me in the context of software or a website or even a physical prototype.  I wouldn't even blink or notice odd word choice.  (Just my experience, from a US gen X military and corporate perspective.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).